# Dpac File - Errors

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a problem with unresolved referenced in synonyms with a VS2013 Database project I have created for Team Foundation Server, which cause the project to not build. The synonyms reference another Database on the same server. I have seen online there are 3 main ways people handle this. I am going for this approach 1.

1. Create a DPAC file and add as a Database reference in Visual Studio Database Project.

   2. Bring in the other database project in the current team Foundation Server project ?
   3. Set the build action to None for the failing scripts that have the unreferenced synomns.

So when I go to extract the DPAC file from the Database it fails with an error.

Validation of the schema model for data package failed.
Error SQL71564: Error validating element [UAT_*********]: The element [UAT_*****] has been orphaned from its login and cannot be deployed.

( There is about 9 similar messages with other logons as well)

Is there anyway to bypass this and generate a valid DPAC file from sql server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a .DACPAC file as a reference to your database projects, there is no need for referencing object to have any real code - As long as the signature met the requirements that the reference from Database Project was looking for, it will be just fine (syntactically valid).

You do not have to create a .DACPAC directly from SQL Sever, you can create a new empty Database Project, create/import all objects needed as references and then "Snapshot Project". This will generate valid .DACPAC and keep the size to minimum, which then you can put under source control.

If you wanted to create a .DACPAC from SQL Server, then I am afraid you would have to delete those objects, because it is unable to find logins in master database that are associated with them.

Great article to read about your approach 1 :

[A complex database project](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+Data+Tools+(SSDT)/125435/)

Hope this helps.